# Install modules in all IDEs

Tags: python, importerror

Out of the three python IDEs I have installed in my system, two of them have some modules (such as `numpy`).
When I try to import that module in ide it is showing me that module is not present.
Next I tried to pip install the modules but then it displayed this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.14.3)
```

Actually the problem is that i have anaconda and its showing that packages are install in anaconda folder so when i m trying to import module in IDLE its showing that module is not installed but if i do same thing in anaconda or pycharm i m not getting any error and if i try to install the module it shows the it has already been installed

Comment: The libraries in your command line context don't necessarily have anything to do with a given IDE. Surely your IDE has documentation on how to do this? Otherwise, this question is specific to your environment using your specific unnamed IDEs. I'm not sure how this could be answered. I'd back up and describe the problem in more details, showing messages or errors as searchable text in the question itself.

Comment: Actually the problem is that i have anaconda and its showing that packages are install in anaconda folder so when i m trying to import module in IDLE its showing that module is not installed but if i do same thing in anaconda or pycharm i m not getting any error and if i try to install the module it shows the it has already been installed

Comment: Your comment should be part of the question as an [edit]. Again, the fact that IDLE can't find what some other tool can is not surprising. If this is possible, you have to tell IDLE where to find libraries and resources. Consult your documentation, do some web searches ("anaconda install libraries for IDLE"), or switch to the Anaconda IDE.